# Check specific folder exists on s3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, fog

I am using Fog Storage to upload my files to s3. I have to check whether a folder exists or not.I don't need the prefix function because it checks the starting. I need something which matches the folder name accurately

**Structure of the s3**

```
mynewbucket(bucketname)
nhdata-231(folder or directory name)
rsadata-56787(folder or directory name)
pfadata-1456(folder or directory name)
```

I have to check whether a specific folder is present or not. I am sharing my code

```
  s3 = Fog::Storage.new({
                :provider                 => 'AWS',
                :aws_access_key_id        => ENV["ACCESSKEYID"],
                :aws_secret_access_key    => ENV["SECRETACCESSKEY"],
                :region                   => 'us-east-2'
             })

    directory = s3.directories.get(ENV["BUCKET"])
//Here I have to check before creating any folder whether it exist or not.
                file = directory.files.create(key: full_bucket_path, public: true)
                file.body = image_contents
                file.save
                file.public_url
```

Comment: S3 has no folders or directories. Everything is a key. Key names can have forward slashes in them, and for human readability, AWS console shows files having forward slashes in their keys as though they were in folders. But you cannot "create a folder" in S3. You can only create a file with a key.

Comment: To extend what @moveson is saying, the slashes in object keys are used by the console to display objects in a folder-like hierarchy, but also, S3 will display an object whose key *ends with* `/` as an empty folder if you create such an object.  But these are entirely unnecessary.  The folders are not containers and do not need to be created before creating objects "in" them, because objects are not in fact "in" them.  The objects simply share the same common prefix up to the last `/` in the object key name.